# Is it possible to import from an existing import?

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

Here are some examples that help explain my question:

```
// ex 1, works
import { MessageAttributeMap } from "aws-sdk/clients/sns";

// ex 2, works
import * as AWS from "aws-sdk";
type MessageAttributeMap = AWS.SNS.MessageAttributeMap

// ex 3, does not work
import * as AWS from "aws-sdk";
import { MessageAttributeMap } from AWS;
```

Example 3 does not work but I was curious if there is a way to perform an import from an existing import?

Is there an alternative way of making ex 2 work with MessageAttributeMap without using AWS.SNS.MessageAttributeMap?

**UPDATE - adding context to the problem**

I have several projects (project a, b, c) that use aws-sdk with the same version. In an attempt reduce the amount of package updates and have all projects use the same version of aws-sdk, I've created a common project (common) that contains aws-sdk.  I've updated all 3 projects to include this common project as a dependency and removed aws-sdk from the 3 projects.

Exporting aws-sdk in common project index.ts:

```
export * as AWS from "aws-sdk";
```

Add common as a dependency in each project's package.json:

```
"@test/common": "file:../../libs/common"
```

Now that I've imported the common project, I would like to update the existing imports to use aws-sdk in the common project from this

```
import * as AWS from "aws-sdk";
import { MessageAttributeMap } from "aws-sdk/clients/sns";
```

to this, if possible

```
import { AWS as aws } from "@test/common"; // works
import { MessageAttributeMap } from aws; // does not work
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I've added more details to the problem above.  I removed aws-sdk from 3 projects and put it in a common project to keep the versions consistent. It works but I'm running into an import problem and was wondering how I can easily resolve the import problems since I'm now referencing aws-sdk from the common dependency.

Comment: I doubt that actually solves your problem - now you'll have different versions of *common* in your 3 projects, instead of different versions of *aws-sdk*!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer to your question is no, since when you call `import * as AWS` you have at that point already imported the entire package into an object. At this point you interact with `AWS` as a regular object, so something like:

```
const { SNS: { MessageAttributeMap } } = AWS;
```

However, if you have a common package, then that makes things a bit easier.
What I suggest you do, is import `AWS` in your common package, then only export those parts you want. So For instance:

```
// packages/common/src/index.ts
import * as AWS from 'aws-sdk';

const { SNS: { MessageAttributeMap } } = AWS;

export MessageAttributeMap;
```

In this way you only export those things you want, directly from your custom workspace, allowing you to import as:

```
import { MessageAttributeMap } from 'aws';
```